# How do I set a custom location for requests?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

How can I set the location for all requests to, for example, *New York*? So, if a user asks for the weather without specifying the location, it'll default to *New York*.

Comment: Write an updateLocationUI() method to set the location controls on the map. If the user has granted location permission, enable the My Location layer and the related control on the map, otherwise disable the layer and the control, and set the current location to null:

Answer (score 0):

It´s not that clear but I figure out that you must refer to the source for weather info (maybe an API) by previously checking if user has it´s location shared and then get from the source using the default location.

It looks like more a coding solution than a functionality for the Google Assistant.

Something like:

```
const LOCATION = user.location || 'New York';
requestMyAPI(LOCATION);
```